# React Native Geolocation await function not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, geolocation, android-location

I am trying to get geolocation from the react-native package "**@react-native-community/geolocation**". on button click I want to get latitude and longitude, for that, I am creating a separate function called getUserCurrentLocation() but I want to make this function as async-await type.

```
const getUserCurrentLocation = () async => {
   await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      info => {
        setGeo({
          lat: info.coords.latitude,
          long: info.coords.longitude,
        });
        console.log(info.coords.latitude + '#' + info.coords.longitude);  
      },
      error => console.log(error),
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 10,
        distanceFilter: 0,
      },
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move async behind the parentheses. that's how to use async and await with try and catch block

```js
const getUserCurrentLocation = async () => {
 try {
  const info = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
  setGeo({
   lat: info.coords.latitude,
   long: info.coords.longitude,
  });
  console.log(info.coords.latitude + '#' + info.coords.longitude); 
 } catch(error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
};
```

but I saw on Documents you don't need to use a promise the is an example and it should work normally:
Visit [https://github.com/react-native-geolocation/react-native-geolocation/blob/master/example/GeolocationExample.js#:~:text=componentDidMount()%20%7B-,Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(,)%3B,-this.watchID%20%3D%20Geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-geolocation/react-native-geolocation/blob/master/example/GeolocationExample.js#:%7E:text=componentDidMount()%20%7B-,Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(,)%3B,-this.watchID%20%3D%20Geolocation)

```js
 Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
   position => {
    const initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
    this.setState({initialPosition});
   },
   error => Alert.alert('Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
   {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000},
    );
```

Comment: Thank you soo much you just save my life